# Replicate drop shadow effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, interface-design, drop-shadow

I'm trying to replicate a drop shadow effect displayed [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/91304073/split-neumorphism-ui-ux-payment-app), but can't seem to get it right.

The project has this section which seems to explain how to perform the effect, but I feel I'm doing something wrong with the mode of the drop shadow, as the black always seems to dominate, or the white doesn't 'pop' enough.

[image]

Would somebody be able to explain how to replicate this effect in Adobe Illustrator?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be done the same way you would make it in CSS, just by adding *another* drop shadow to the path.

Just apply your drop shadow (**Effect → Stylize → Drop Shadow**) and then repeat the steps - only this time you have to inverse the direction of your drop shadow.

<sup>(Illustrator will ask you to confirm that you are re-applying the same effect.)</sup>

If you want the white to *pop* more, just increase the opactiy (make it less transparent) and decrease the opacity on your darker color.

Also, because it is a light colored background, I had to change the blending mode on the white from multiply to normal.

---

This is a quick sample I managed to produce in Illustrator

[image: sample]

Here's the [Illustrator File](https://github.com/WELZ-gh/Drafts/raw/master/Saved/IllustratorFiles/neumorphism.ai) you can check out to see how I accomplished it.

Comment: Note, in my sample - I did not follow the directions mentioned in their image.